# DataBase cursor illegal state exception

Tags: android, database, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm retrieving a string from the Product field:

```
public class Product {
private int _id;
private int _quantity;

public Product() {
}

public Product(int id, int quantity) {
    this._id = id;
    this._quantity = quantity;
}

public Product(int quantity) {

    this._quantity = quantity;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this._id = id;
}

public int getID() {
    return this._id;
}


public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this._quantity = quantity;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return this._quantity;
}
```

}

with a cursor in the DBHander class, i do the same thing for the last 10 Products added to the db:

```
public int[] retrieveNumbers(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    int[] numbers;
    numbers = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int i;
    if(cursor.moveToLast()){
        cursor.moveToLast();
        for(i=0; i<10; i++){
            numbers[i]=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1));
            if(cursor.moveToPrevious()){
                cursor.moveToPrevious();
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return numbers;
    }else{
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

the error is: cursorindexoutofboundexception -1 requested with a size of 2

help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving two position intead one. The method `cursor.moveToPrevious()` return `true`and move it to the previous position, but you are moving it one more time:

```
 if(cursor.moveToLast()){
    boolean finished = false;
    for(i=0; i<10 && !finished; i++){
        numbers[i]=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1));
        if(!cursor.moveToPrevious())
        {
           finished = true;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return numbers;
}else{
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: thank you! it works i'm going to accept your answer as soon as the site will let me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor doesn't have 10 rows it is returning just 2 rows.
Try looping on the size of cursor  `cursor.getCount()` .